# ¿Cómo enmascarar una url cuando los dos hosting y dominios afectados están en el mismo servidor?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

¿Cómo hago para enmascarar una url?

Lo he hecho en el `.htaccess` con este código:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^eipr.unipaz.edu.co
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://eipr.xyz/$1 [P]
```

pero lo que hace es redireccionarlo, no enmascararlo.
Los dos dominios corresponden a 2 host compartidos en un mismo servidor, es decir, tienen la misma dirección ip. Uso Cpanel y WHM

Hacerlo con php, no me sirve, debido a que al hacer clic en cualquier vínculo de la página con el dominio enmascarado por este método, me lleva a las páginas respectivas en el mismo sitio con la url sin enmascarar.

Comment: Pues a mi ese dominio me sale bien, no me redirecciona ahora mismo... ¿ya lo has solucionado?